# Cuda efficient insertion of data into unsorted populated array

Tags: c++, arrays, search, insert, cuda

I have two arrays within Cuda;

```
int *main; // unsorted
int *source; // sorted
```

Part of my algorithm requires that I regulary insert new data into the main array from the source array.  If a position within the main array is zero, it assumes it is empty, therefore it can be populated with a value from the source array.

I'm just wondering what the most efficient method of doing this is, I've tried a couple of approaches but still think there are some more performance gains to be made here.

Currently I'm using a modified version of a radix sort, to "shuffle" the contents of the main array to the very end of the main array, leaving all zero values at the beginning of the array, making the insertion from source trivial.  The sort has been modified to iterate over a single bit, rather than 32 bits, this works with a simple switch on the input;

```
input[i] = source[i] > 1 ? 1 : 0
```

I'm wondering if this is already quite an efficient way of doing this?  I'm wondering if I wouldn't gain something by using a tactically deployed atomicAdd such as;

```
__global__ void find(int *destination, int *indices, const int N)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if((destination[idx] == 0)&&(count<elements_to_add))
    {
        indices[count] = idx;
        atomicAdd(&count, 1);
    }
}

__global__ void insert(int *destination, int *indices, int *source, const int N)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if((source[idx] > 0)&&(indices[idx] > 0))
    {
        destination[indices[idx]] = source[idx];
    }
}

find<<<G,T>>>(...);
insert<<<G,T>>>(...);
```

I'm not inserting that many items via the source array at the moment, but that could changing in the future.

This feels like it should be a common problem that has been solved before, I'm wondering if the thrust library may help, but having a browse for appropriate functions it doesn't quite feel right for what I'm trying to accomplish (not very neatly fitting with the code I already have)

Thoughts from experienced Cuda developers appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to preserve the ordering of elements in the source when you insert them into the destination?

Comment: No, I don't need to preserve the ordering of elements in the source.

Comment: ..no idea why this has been down voted twice.

Comment: You could start by defining what you mean by "efficient", and perhaps explaining how you have arrived at the conclusion that the code (which you haven't shown) isn't "efficient".

Comment: If you felt that my definition of efficient wasn't explained well enough, perhaps a comment would've been better, establishing a dialogue and a better documented question..?  rather than just a down vote with no explanation. I think it's a safe assumption that if I'm talking about Cuda I care about performance, therefore efficient, means fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can decouple your finding algorithm, which is categorized as a stream compaction procedure, and your insertion , which is categorized as scatter procedure. However, you can merge the functionality of the two.

Assuming `srcPtr` is a pointer that its content resides inside the global memory and is already set to zero before the kernel launch.

```
__global__ void find_and_insert( int* destination, int const* source, int const N, int* srcPtr ) {    // Assuming N is the length of the destination buffer and also the length of the source buffer is less than N.

int const idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

// Get the assigned element.
int const dstElem = destination[ idx ];
bool const pred = ( dstElem == 0 );

// Intra-warp binary reduction to count the total number of lanes with empty elements.
int const predBallot = __ballot( pred );
int const intraWarpRed = __popc( predBallot );

// Warp-aggregated atomics to reduce the contention over the srcPtr content.
unsigned int laneID; asm( "mov.u32 %0, %laneid;" : "=r"(laneID) ); //const uint laneID = tidWithinCTA & ( WARP_SIZE - 1 );
int posW;
if( laneID == 0 )
    posW = atomicAdd( srcPtr, intraWarpRed );
posW = __shfl( posW, 0 );

// Threads that have found empty elements can fill out their assigned positions from the src. Intra-warp binary prefix sum is used here.
uint laneMask; asm( "mov.u32 %0, %lanemask_lt;" : "=r"(laneMask) ); //const uint laneMask =  0xFFFFFFFF >> ( WARP_SIZE - laneID ) ;
int const positionToRead = posW + __popc( predBallot & laneMask );
if( pred )
    destination[ idx ] = source[ positionToRead ];

}
```

A few things:

1. This kernel is just a suggestion on how you can do it. Here threads inside the warps collaborate on the task. You can extend the binary reduction and prefix sum over the thread-block.
2. I wrote this kernel inside the browser and haven't tested it. So be careful.
3. The whole design is not something new. Similar approaches have been implemented (for example [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=7429293&filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A7429279%29)) and is mostly based on [the work done by Mark Harris and Michael Garland](http://booksite.elsevier.com/samplechapters/9780123859631/Chapter_3.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Farzad, much appreciated.